# Рюкзак с взаимоисключениями

Tags: алгоритм

Существует ли алгоритм, сходный с [задачей о упаковке рюкзака](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5), но с взаимоисключениями? То есть если мы взяли, например, первый предмет то не можем брать третий и пятый и наоборот.

Comment: Не понимаю что мешает вам сначала выбрать порядок заполнения предметов на основании его определить исключения и дальше решать обычную задачу о рюкзаке.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "Выбрать порядок заполнения предметов"?

Comment: Взаимоисключения некомутативны. Для простоты пусть есть только три предмета для упаковки a b c. a исключает с, c исключает b. Тогда может существовать не 3! = 6 вариантов порядка упаковки а меньше.
abc - > ab (a исключает с)
acb - > ab (a исключает с)
cab - > ca (c исключает b) 
cba - > ca (c исключает b)
bac - > ba (a исключает с)
bca - > bca (Здесь поведение зависит от того действует ли исключение на то что уже есть в порядке)

То есть исключения влияют исключительно на порядок упаковки а не на сам алгоритм(куда класть). Поэтому надо сначала определиться с ними.

Comment: Для данной задачи не важен порядок упаковки. Пусть у нас есть предметы весами 1 2 и 3 и рюкзак вместимостью 4. При том если мы взяли предмет весом 1 то мы не может взять предмет весом 3 и наоборот. При этом неважно, как они будут размещены в рюкзаке, важно то, предметы с какими массами мы возьмём

Comment: Тогда у вас есть 
(12, 21, 32, 23) 4 варианта входных данных для обычной задаче о рюкзаке. 2(решение самой задачи не зависит от порядка предметов конечно) раза решаем её и выбираем лучший рюкзак из полученных.

Comment: И какую ассимптотику будет иметь такое решение?

Comment: O(n*A) для решения задач о рюкзаке.(A сложность выбранного алгоритма решения задачи о рюкзаке. n число рюкзаков). O(n) для выбора лучшего рюкзака(n - число рюкзаков). (Просто найти максимум в массиве) O(A) для генерации входных рюкзаков. A - сложность выбранного алгоритма генерации перестановок. O(n) для извлечения из полученных перестановок исключений.(n - число перестановок)

Как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

Для данной задачи не важен порядок упаковки. Пусть у нас есть предметы весами 1 2 и 3 и рюкзак вместимостью 4. При том если мы взяли предмет весом 1 то мы не может взять предмет весом 3 и наоборот. При этом неважно, как они будут размещены в рюкзаке, важно то, предметы с какими массами мы возьмём

Я, конечно, извиняюсь, может сейчас не в тему ляпну или глупость отмочу, но почему нельзя из вместимости рюкзака отнять вместимость вещей, включая предпологаемую, которую проверяем на вхождение? Если разность положительная - вещь берем, если отрицательная - не влазит.....

Comment: У вас рюкзак вместимостью 6 и вещи массами 4 3 и 3. По вашему алгоритму вы возьмете 4 и остановитесь. Хотя есть и более оптимальный вариант (3 + 3)